# Jacoco can not find classes directory in multi-module maven project and generates empty html report

Tags: java, maven, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

In my multi-module project I have a code and tests in separate modules. When I run maven command `'mvn clean install -DskipTests=false'`, jacoco.exec file is generated in test module but Jacoco complains about missing classes directory. In jacoco-report module, the report is generated but its empty.

How can I configure it to generate report or to be more specific how can I point Jacoco to the classes directory?

Here is structure of my project:

[image: Code structure]

My pom file from 'multi-module':

```
 <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>
                        --illegal-access=permit
                    </argLine>
                    <argLine>@{argLine}</argLine>
                    <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
                    <skipTests>${skipTests}</skipTests>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.3</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.10</version>
                <configuration>
                    <destFile>${project.basedir}/../multi-module-core/target/jacoco.exec</destFile>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-site</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <dataFile>${project.basedir}/../multi-module-tests/target/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
                            <includes>
                                <include>${project.basedir}/../multi-module-core/target/classes/**</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>`
```

Pom file from 'multi-module-core':

```
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.3</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.3</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Pom file from 'multi-module-tests':

```
   <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>@{argLine}</argLine>
                    <skipTests>${skipTests}</skipTests>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>.</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.log</include>
                            </includes>
                            <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.3</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Pom file from 'jacoco-report':

```
  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report-aggregate</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report-aggregate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <dataFileIncludes>
                                <dataFileInclude>**/jacoco.exec</dataFileInclude>
                            </dataFileIncludes>
                            <outputDirectory>
                                ${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-aggregate
                            </outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

So far I tried multiple configurations from all over the internet but with the same result. Appreciate any help or suggestions.

**EDIT 1**:
As suggested I run mvn command in debug mode:

```
mvn clean verify -DskipTests=false -X
```

IT turns out that the following path is wrong:

```
<include>${project.basedir}/../multi-module-core/target/classes/**</include>
```

and it points to :  **[C:\Projects\jococo\test\multi-module\multi-module-tests/../multi-module-core/target/classes/**]**  .

But even when I hard coded the path to **C:\Projects\jococo\test\multi-module\multi-module-core\target\classes**

Here is what I got during jacoco:report phase:

[image]

```
 includes = [C:\Projects\jococo\test\multi-module\multi-module-core\target\classes]
```

It looks like the paths pointing to the correct directory with classes but I still got the same error message: **Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing classes directory.**

**EDIT 2:**

For the reference here is GitHub repo to the project:  https://github.com/KonarzewskiP/jacoco-multi-module

Comment: First why do you have unit tests in a separate module instead of the module where the code lives? What is the reason? What kind of problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Also using old versions of maven-surefire-plugin, maven-compiler-plugin etc. I strongy recommend to upgrade to the most recent version for all plugin check here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/

Comment: This is simplified version of the project which I am working on. The real project has junit SOAP tests under '.src.test.java' folder and xml files with SOAP tests under 'test.souapui' folder. In the 'multi-module' project, I intentionally used the old versions of the dependencies, because they are the same ones  I use in my work project.

Comment: So this means first SOAP tests are integration tests and should be executed by failsafe-plugin with the appropriate naming convention (*IT.java).. also that means you should update your project. Apart from that it does not answer my question why you have unit tests in a separate module which makes no sense ... unit tests should be in the same module as your production code which you are testing.

Comment: You are right, having unit tests in separate project does not make sense. The only reason why i did this in 'multi-module' project, was to simplify the structure of my work project and highlight the  "Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing classes directory." error.  So if I understand it correct, the only possibility to generate JaCoCo report in case of 'multi-module' project, is to configure it as a integration test?

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons for the problem, but consider this step to find out the configuration missing section.

1. Check Data File Location:
   In your `multi-module-tests` module's `pom.xml`, ensure that the `jacoco.exec` file is being generated in the correct location. The `destFile` property should specify the full path to where the `jacoco.exec` file should be saved, which is typically within the target directory of the module.

   ```
   <configuration>
       <destFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco.exec</destFile>
   </configuration>
   ```
2. Check Include Patterns:
   In the `jacoco-report` module's `pom.xml`, your `<dataFileIncludes>` pattern should match the location of `jacoco.exec` files from all your modules. Make sure it's set correctly to include all the modules.

   ```
   <dataFileIncludes>
       <dataFileInclude>/target/jacoco.exec</dataFileInclude>
   </dataFileIncludes>
   ```
3. Ensure Correct Execution Order:
   When running `mvn clean install -DskipTests=false`, make sure that the modules are executed in the correct order. Dependencies between modules must be resolved in the right sequence to ensure that coverage data is collected properly.
4. Run `verify` Phase:
   Ensure that you run the `verify` phase to generate the reports in the `jacoco-report` module, as specified in your `jacoco-report` module's `pom.xml`.

   mvn clean verify
5. Verify Relative Paths:
   Double-check that relative paths are correctly configured in your POM files, especially for properties like `destFile`. Relative paths should be based on the current module's location.
6. Plugin Versions Compatibility:
   Verify that you are using compatible versions of Maven, JaCoCo, and related plugins. Incompatibilities can lead to issues with report generation.
7. Debugging Output:
   Enable debugging output (`-X` flag) when running Maven (`mvn clean install -DskipTests=false -X`) to get more detailed information about what is happening during the build process. This might help pinpoint the issue.
8. Check Classpath Configuration:
   Ensure that the classes and test classes directories are correctly configured in your POM files for both the `jacoco-maven-plugin` and the `maven-surefire-plugin`. Verify that the `includes` section in `jacoco-maven-plugin` covers the classes you want to include in the report.

After making these adjustments, try running the build again (`mvn clean verify`) and check if the JaCoCo report is generated correctly in the `jacoco-report` module with the expected coverage data.

Hope I was helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Unfortunately, I double checked everything and it seems all good.

Comment: Can you explain that part: `Verify that you are using compatible versions of Maven, JaCoCo, and related plugins.`?

Comment: To address this, you should consult the documentation for each tool and library you're using in your project to find information on their compatible versions. Typically, these documents will specify which versions are known to work well together. You may need to update or downgrade one or more of these components to ensure compatibility.